# Is there any way to input text in Apple Watch

Tags: ios, watchkit

In my Apple Watch app I need to input text, so is there any way to input text in my app with voiceOver or any other ways?

As I have seen none of the objects in WKInterfaceController support editable text inputs like UITextfield or UITextview.

Answer (score 8):

The above answer has no code, just a link to Apple's awesome XD documentation.
You can launch a speech recognition menu with some voice options using this code (WatchOS2, iOS 9.2.1):

```
//LAUNCH VOICE DICTATION (physical device only)
    func launchVoiceDictationMenu(){
        self.presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions(["Hello","Goodbye","Hey"], allowedInputMode: WKTextInputMode.Plain,
            completion:{(results) -> Void in
                let aResult = results?[0] as? String
                print(aResult)
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Update with swift 3 watchOS 3 Scribble mode

```
presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: ["watchOS3"], allowedInputMode:   WKTextInputMode.plain) { (arr: [Any]?) in
        print(arr ?? "Not find")
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

With watchOS 3 welcome the new "scribble" mode

```
[self presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions:@[@"watchOS3"]; allowedInputMode:WKTextInputModePlain completion:^(NSArray *array){

    if (array != nil) {

        for (int i=0; i<[array count]; i++) {

            NSString *str = [array objectAtIndex:0];

            NSLog(@"%@",str);
        }

    }

}];
```

[image] [image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can input text in Apple Watch using dictation (the watch has a microphone) or by selecting an emoji right on the screen. From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/TextandLabels.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014969-CH19-SW1):

> WatchKit provides a standard modal interface for retrieving text input
>   from the user. When presented, the interface allows the user to enter
>   text via dictation or to select from a standard set of phrases or
>   emoji.

Comment: Thanks Nikos, it helps a lot. If possible please share the sample of code.

Comment: @AbhishekSinha the link to apple documentation has also code samples for text input :-)

Comment: @AbhishekSinha I wrote a quick blog post that might help you: http://www.fiveminutewatchkit.com/blog/2015/3/15/how-to-get-text-input-from-the-user

Comment: A nice tutorial for text input using WatchKit http://natashatherobot.com/watchkit-text-input-dictation-api/

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4

```
@IBAction func ReplyWithTextInputController(){

    let phrases = ["OK", "I'm busy.", "Where are you?", "Thanks."]

    presentTextInputController(withSuggestions: phrases,
                                    allowedInputMode: WKTextInputMode.allowEmoji, completion: { (result) -> Void in

                                        guard let choice = result else {
                                            return
                                        }
                                        let suggestion = choice[0]
                                        print(suggestion)

                        })

}
```